# Jade conditional statement is not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, pug

I have a mixin like this:

```
  mixin res-nav(items, type)
      if type === 1
          ul
            each item, key in items
              - if (typeof(item.liClass) === 'undefined') item.liClass = ''
              - if (typeof(item.urlClass) === 'undefined') item.urlClass = ''
              li(class='h_menu_iconss' + item.liClass)
                +link(item.title, item.href, item.text)(class='h_menu_link' + item.urlClass)
                if (typeof(item.itemsMenu) !== 'undefined')
                  +nav(item.itemsMenu, 2)
      if type ===2
          ul(class="submenu")
            each item, key in items
              - if (typeof(item.liClass) === 'undefined') item.liClass = ''
              - if (typeof(item.urlClass) === 'undefined') item.urlClass = ''
              li(class='subitem' + item.liClass)
                +link(item.title, item.href, item.text)(class='h2_menu_link' + item.urlClass)
```

When I use it, if type is equal to 2, the mixin just output raw **ul li**  elements without any class intergrated into them like these:

```
 <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Accommodation</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Adult Educatoin</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Children</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Cuisine</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Culture</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Destinations</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Exploring</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Exploring</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Getting Around</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Health &amp; Beauty</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Rules &amp; Regulations</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Shopping</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sports &amp; Excercise</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Work &amp; Business</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Miscellaneous</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Any suggestions? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Weird... It works for me. I have made a pen with a simplified version of your code and it works : https://codepen.io/jeremythille/pen/adBJmP Classes are here on the UL and the LI

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I made a mistake here: **+nav(item.itemsMenu, 2)** that must be changed to       **+res-nav(item.itemsMenu, 2)**
Anw, thank you very much for all of your help! :)